# Can't discover a IPv4 link-local address when having an static IP configured

Tags: networking, local-area-network, ipv4, avahi, link-local

I have link-local addresses working out-of-the-box when coupled with DHCP, since when there's no DHCP, the device doesn't get an IP, only a link-local one. Still, I need to have link-local addresses working even if I'm setting up interfaces statically. I'm not sure how I should proceed. This is what I've done:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
        iface eth0 inet static
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        address 192.168.0.25
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        post-up /usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd --force-bind --daemonize --wait $IFACE 2> /dev/null
        pre-down /usr/sbin/avahi-autoipd --kill $IFACE 2> /dev/null
```

And this is the result:

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:63:b4:00:88:1f
          inet addr:192.168.0.25  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:881f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:554 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:33114 (33.1 KB)  TX bytes:56243 (56.2 KB)

eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:63:b4:00:88:1f
          inet addr:169.254.5.135  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

All nice, my target got 2 local IP's. Now, I want to access it by connecting a network cable directly. I can't browse it with avahi-browse, "avahi-browse -alr" only returns the 192.168.0.25 static address or the IPv6 link-local, never the IPv4 link-local one. I'm able to ssh the target using the 169.254.5.135 link-local address! and I can't do it with the static address avahi-browse reports, because there's no route for it, it's just a cable connection. I just dunno how I can *discover* this link-local IP... It's the last piece in this puzzle since the link-local IP is working. It's like the static configuration is taking precedence over discovering.

Notice that all machines are reporting the avahi workstation service.

### EDIT

Ah, I've forgot to set the publish workstation service on the target avahi-daemon.conf. So, after setting this, behavior has changed. `avahi-browse -ar`, even when executed from inside the target, is not listing its own link-local address, only its IPv6 and the static IPv4. So, if the target itself can't browse this link-local address anymore, how could the connected machine do it in the first place. I dunno how to make avahi-browse list this address that is valid.

```
~ ❯❯❯ ssh francisco@169.254.5.135                                                                                                                  archlinux ✱
francisco@169.254.5.135's password:
  ____      _                 _ ____     __  __
 / ___|   _| |__   _____  __ (_)___ \ ___\ \/ /
| |  | | | | '_ \ / _ \ \/ / | | __) / _ \\  /
| |__| |_| | |_) | (_) >  <  | |/ __/  __//  \
 \____\__,_|_.__/ \___/_/\_\ |_|_____\___/_/\_\


Welcome to ARMBIAN Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 3.14.60-cubox

System load:   0.00             Up time:       35 min
Memory usage:  5 % of 3788Mb    IP:            192.168.0.25
CPU temp:      47°C
Usage of /:    4% of 29G

Last login: Wed Feb 24 04:19:27 2016 from 169.254.4.29
francisco@cubox-i:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d0:63:b4:00:88:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.5.135/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope link eth0:avahi
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.0.25/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:881f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether f6:4b:80:39:3e:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:ad:f8:1d:4b:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
francisco@cubox-i:~$ avahi-browse -ar
+   eth0 IPv6 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
+   eth0 IPv4 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
=   eth0 IPv6 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
   hostname = [cubox-i.local]
   address = [fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:881f]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
=   eth0 IPv4 cubox-i [d0:63:b4:00:88:1f]                   Workstation          local
   hostname = [cubox-i.local]
   address = [192.168.0.25]
   port = [9]
   txt = []
```

Answer (score 1):

The truth is that I can access the static IP 192.168.0.25! The issue was that I was trying to communicate using direct cable while my notebook was connected to WiFi, inside a 192.168.0.0/24 network. When turning off WiFi I'm able to access 192.168.0.25.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I see why your statement

> It's like the static configuration is taking precedence over discovering.

is partly correct. At least the behavior is explainable.

Avahi only publishes link-local addresses, if they are the only ones on the link, see
[https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/blob/1cc2b8e8d62e939b8bd683f795794878863931af/avahi-core/iface.c#L707][1].
You can also observe this behavior when running avahi-daemon on your interface configuration, the output states which addresses are published.
As there are two IPv4 addresses (static and link-local), the local one is not published.
For IPv6 you only have a link-local one, which you accordingly see on your avahi-browse.

As Wikipedia states

> RFC 3927 warns against the simultaneous use of IPv4 addresses of different scope,[6] such as configuring link-local addresses as well as globally routable addresses on the same interface. Therefore, hosts search for a DHCP server on the network before assigning link-local addresses.

So I think this behavior is intended, and forcing a link-local address for static configurations is discouraged.